# Integrate OpenGL in Cocos2dx

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, word-wrap

This might be a trivial question, but here is this issue I wonder about cocos2d-x in general. I've read somewhere cocos2d and cocos2dx are based on OpenGL ES (2.0 i guess?). And also from the creators of cocos2dx that OpenGL ES 2.0 is not yet enabled in it.
This sounds to me like someone saying Obj-C is written based on C, but C is not yet enables in Obj-C!
is there anyway (coz I couldn't find any nice tutorial on the net anywhere) to integrate OpenGL ES 1.0/2.0 in cocos2dx?

If not, write OpenGL ES 2.0 in Obj-C and integrate in cocos2dx, .cpp files. (use classes etc, maybe wrapping objects from Obj-C, but how would I wrap a large class inherited from UIView [to alter draw() method] to be able to use in .cpp file in my cocos2dx project?)

Very much appreciate your help in advance,

P.S. I have been like a sitting duck for the past month, thanks to this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The link you referred to in a comment is one year older. Check this one out instead: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Download

OpenGL ES 2.0 is now supported now in cocos2dX.

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2d-x is written in C++ and OpenGL ES 1.1/2.0, so OpenGL ES is already supported (integrated).

Comment: I was hoping and assuming the same thing but quote from Walzer Wang himself: "2.0 support is not coming so fast in cocos2d-x." http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/3607     could you please show me an example of how would I use OpenGL ES 1.0/2.0 in my cocos2d-x project? or a link would be appreciable

Comment: actually I am using some openGL code since cocos2d-x 1.x. most of them just overwrite the default visit() or draw() function in a CCSprite and write your own code there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I wonder how that is possible. Would appreciate if you could share some code here. From what you have just said seems I have not fully understood opengl es and whereabouts I can use its libraries. Thanks again!